# Can Bluedroid be used in raspberry pi instead of BlueZ

Tags: bluetooth

I was going through the bluedroid architecture and how it works and all those stuffs [here](http://mre4less.com/blog/2016/10/07/wanna-learn-about-bluedroid-in-simple-terms-keep-reading-this-section/). I wanted to know whether we can use bluedroid stack instead of bluez in raspbian. If its possible how can it be done since bluedroid does not support dbus?

Comment: Presumably bluedroid is an android application, what makes you think it would be a drop in replacement on Linux? Are you running Android on your Pi?

Comment: Hi @Steve. I'm not using android in my Pi. From what I understood from this [article](https://bitbucket.org/lememta/cava/wiki/Enable%20Bluetooth(Turn%20on%20bluetooth)), Java is used near the application layer and JNI is used to convert the calls to native C function calls. Hence the lower layers are implemented in C. That's why I was curious to know whether somehow it can be used in Pi/Linux. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: We have ported the complete bluedroid to Linux. It requires customizing the HCI layer for Linux, customizing the thread's. It is quite a big work. We have spent few months to get it working in Linux. Let me know if you are interested still, I can share you the details further

Answer (score 3):

Yes it can be used but not easily...

You have to have little expertise in C Programming .

Check ESP32 , they are using Bluedroid in FReeRTOS.

You have to go in similar way .. so basically You have to write your own application layer routines to drive the API of Bluedroid.

ESP32 people have used snipped version of bluedroid .i.e. All the Java Codes has been dropped from bluedroid .. and they have written simple basic application which talks to the top layer of Bluedroid C Files.

Short Answer to your question is: Yes it is achievable and if you follow the ESP32 way , You can have bluedroid running all in User Space.

Answer (score 0):

It is quite different between those two bluetooth stacks
I don't see anyone porting bluedroid to raspberry
even someone porting it to rpi
you still need applications to let it work

There is a new version of bluedroid, called fluoride, and it could be compiled on a linux/ubuntu distro. 
But it does not fully ready for end-user usage (maybe for chromebook?)
event you compile it on ubuntu, you still need bluetooth applications to use those bluetooth features
They can NOT run with bluedroid/fluroide bluetooth stack
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/bt/

android and linux are different. although android uses the linux-kernel and it changes a lot things.
application and standard libraries are different
android has java blueooth application to some feature, like radio-on, file-sending...
it use a lot android framework feature and it is not effective to porting whole android framework to rpi
It needs a lot of work to re-write those application/GUI

bluedroid does not use dbus, it use apache license, donated to google by broadcom company

if you are a end-user, you may buy a cheaper cellphone or use a android-x86 to use bluedroid
if you are interesting with bluedroid as a developer, you may start to check bluetooth stack specification as a start