# How Bluedroid can be worked in raspberry pi4B instead of BlueZ

Tags: raspbian, bluetooth, dbus

Want to port the bluedroid to raspberry pi4B instead of BlueZ. Because of some causes, only want to use the pi's rootfs, don't use the dbus. how to work it?

1. first of all, as we know，different platform uses different hci
   interface to adapte the kernel bt driver;
2. second and the most difficulty is that bt profile app how to use btif to communicate with stack.

Answer (score 0):

From this previous questions it seems like it is not a trivial exercise:
[Can Bluedroid be used in raspberry pi instead of BlueZ](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/69682/121848)

If you need to avoid using D-Bus, then have you looked at the BlueZ Bluetooth Management API?
https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/doc/mgmt-api.txt

There are various options at compile to remove parts of BlueZ that are not required on a system:
https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/README

Comment: In the long run, I think using bluedroid mybe much better.